# How to Include Common Sidebar or Header in All Scenes JavaFX FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm learning JavaFX and facing problem in sharing the same resources on the all scene.

Example as in PHP we can include common page like `include("header.php");` or `include("sidebar.php");`

But how I can add same sidebar on the all scenes/stages in JavaFX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`<fx:include>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements):

```xml
<BorderPane>
    <top>
        <fx:include source="header.fxml"/>
    </top>
    <left>
        <fx:include source="sidebar.fxml"/>
    </left>
    <center>
        <!-- ... -->
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```